# Abstract types in method parameters

Tags: scala, generics, types, abstract-type

There's a simple example in Programming in Scala by Odersky et al on abstract types, but it does not seem to follow to it's logical conclusion [now edited to make this my exact code]:

```
class Food
class Grass extends Food
class FishFood extends Food

abstract class Animal {
  type Feed <: Food
  def eat(food: Feed)
}

class Cow extends Animal {
  type Feed = Grass
  override def eat(food: Grass) = {}
}

class Test extends App {
  val cow: Animal = new Cow
  cow.eat(new FishFood)
  cow.eat(new Grass)
}
```

They explain this will prevent me doing (as above):

```
val cow: Animal = new Cow
cow.eat(new FishFood)
```

So far so good. But the next natural step does not seem to work either:

```
cow.eat(new Grass)
```

I get a compile error:

```
type mistmatch;
found : Grass
required: Test.this.cow.Feed
 cow.eat(new Grass)
         ^
```

But cow.Feed is Grass, so why doesn't this work?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. I can feed my cow :) Please provide the erroneous code as well.

Comment: What version of Scala?  I just saw in the REPL for Scala 2.9.0.1 that this does indeed happen.  It might  be a bug in that version...

Comment: @lulian The listing now shows what I'm trying to compile

Comment: @Don now tried in 2.10 M6 and 2.9.2 on Windows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that your val `cow` is typed as `Animal` rather than `Cow`, so all that the compiler knows is that its `eat` method expects some specific subtype of `Food`, but it doesn't know which, and in particular it's unable to prove that that type is equal to `Grass`.

You can see the difference this makes to the type of the method (as viewed from `Animal` vs. as viewed from `Cow`) by asking for it's eta-expansion,

```
scala> val cow: Animal = new Cow
cow: Animal = Cow@13c02dc4

scala> cow.eat _
res12: cow.Feed => Unit = <function1>

scala> cow.asInstanceOf[Cow].eat _
res13: Grass => Unit = <function1>
```

You'll notice that in the second, more precisely typed, case the compiler views the method as taking an argument of type `Grass` rather than the abstract type `cow.Feed`.

Comment: This is interesting as it seems to highlight a difference between type parameters and abstract types. If I had the `Food` as a parameter, then I could remain abstract about the animal, but not the feed by having `Animal[Grass]` as my type, and still call `eat(new Grass)` on this. Is there no way to do something similar with abstract types in Scala?

Comment: Yes, you could declare your cow with a refinement: `val cow : Animal { type Feed = Grass } = new Cow`.

Answer (score 3):

And it should fail in such way - and actually, I think it is explained in Programming in Scala (2nd edition, p. 460).

On this line:

```
val cow: Animal = new Cow
```

You told the compiler to assume that `cow` could be any animal, including fish - and it certainly would do fish no good to eat grass!

If you would let the compiler to infer the proper type, it would compile:

```
val cow = new Cow
cow.eat(new Grass)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realise that having a `Cow`, rather than an `Animal` type will allow me to feed my cow. But I thought the path-dependent type of `Cow.Feed` of my `cow` instance will allow the instance to take the correct parameter type. In the book they _only_ use the example of trying to feed their cow `FishFood`